# Can Gradle configuration vary based on whether it is being run from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, intellij-idea, ide

I am working on a [Gradle](https://gradle.org) project where some of the tests occasionally fail sporadically due to reasons unrelated to their correctness (specifically, sometimes the [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) Docker containers fail to start up).  This is mitigated using the [Test Retry Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/gradle/test-retry-gradle-plugin) to retry tests on failure, which greatly reduces the chances of such a build failure occurring.

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.gradle.test-retry' version '1.2.0'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    retry {
        maxRetries = 1
    }
}
```

One annoyance with this setup occurs when running individual tests/test classes from the [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) IDE using the default "Run tests using: Gradle" configuration.

When testing code under development from IDEA, failed tests are far more likely to indicate an issue with the in-progress code changes.  Flaky test failures are far rarer, since only a small number of tests are being run.  Flaky test failures are also obvious when they do occur, and less problematic since it's the result of a manual user interaction.

The downsides of retrying tests are that some of the tests take a while to run, and retrying tests in the IDE gives a false sense of how many tests have passed/failed.  For these reasons, I do not want failed tests to be retried when individual tests are run from IDEA.

How can I configure my Gradle project to retry when run from the console, but not from within IntelliJ IDEA?  Bonus points if the solution also works for other Java IDEs (e.g. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/) & [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org)), but a solution that only works for IDEA will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The `idea.active` [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) can be checked for a value of `"true"`, customizing the configuration based on whether it's set:

```groovy
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    if (System.getProperty('idea.active') != 'true') {
        retry {
            maxRetries = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether or where this property is documented, but I have confirmed that it works for the latest version of IDEA (IDEA Ultimate 2020.3.2).